# print a document using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I need to print a document without buttons.Can anyone please guide me to accomplish this task.

I have a button to print in button click onclick() event I have used window.print() to print those data .But In a print preview It shows the page including those 4 buttons.i do not want those buttons I need only those data.

for more information I have adde the image below
[image: my print preview os ubuntu]

Comment: simply hide the buttons then initiate a print

Answer (score 4):

You can specify different css rules for printing. Either you can use the `@media print {}` scope like this:

```
@media print {
    /* Add your custom css rules here */
   input {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Or you can specify an entirely different css file to use like this (if you want to change your black background and white text to something more printer friendly):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Comment: most complete answer. and, much better than hiding things with js before printing...!

Answer (score 3):

add a wrapper to non-printable stuff i.e buttons in your case. check below code :

```html
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #printable {
      display: none;
    }
    @media print {
      #non-printable {
        display: none;
      }
      #printable {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="non-printable">
    Your normal page contents
  </div>

  <div id="printable">
    Printer version
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS `@media print` or a `print` stylesheet to hide the button when it is printed. That way it will be hidden on the printout whether the button is used to print or not.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    #printbtn {
        display :  none;
    }
}
</style>
<input id ="printbtn" type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();" >
```

Refer [@media print](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-media)

[Additional reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/link/media)

Comment: That's a very nice answer.

Comment: ow its nice ,new infromation +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

1 Give your print button an ID:

```
<input id="printpagebutton" type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="printpage()"/>`
```

2. Adjust your script the way that it hides the button before calling 
   window.print():

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function printpage() {
           //Get the print button and put it into a variable
           var printButton = document.getElementById("printpagebutton");
           //Set the print button visibility to 'hidden' 
           printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           //Print the page content
           window.print()
           //Set the print button to 'visible' again 
           //[Delete this line if you want it to stay hidden after printing]
           printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
       }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To simply print a document using javascript, use the following code,

```
print(){

        let w=window.open("www.url.com/pdf"); 
        w.print(); 
        w.close();
    }
```

Comment: How do you specify in that `print()` function new page break? CSS does not work at all.